# Math is the best option in Stack Exchange for ask about math doubts?

Tags: discussion

Hello before nothing  this question is no similar like this:

[i-use-the-site-to-ask-about-specific-topics-in-my-math-learning-is-it-ok](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15214/i-use-the-site-to-ask-about-specific-topics-in-my-math-learning-is-it-ok)

I know **Math** is:

> Mathematics
>   For people studying math at any level and professionals in related fields

ok I understand is for people studying math at any level that meaning I could ask about  any  kind of question about math for example when I do not understand a concept about math at any level this kind of question are correct for this site or what another site is correct for example maybe the best site is:

[this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/)
 or 
[this](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/)
or 
[this](https://mathoverflow.net/)

anyone here could tell me what site is the correct for ask about concept basic about math, I ask this becuase maybe the new member could ask this kind of question  anyday in the future and here they will could find the anwser.

Comment: I am not really sure where the doubt is. Each of these sites has a pretty clear description of the sort of question that goes well on the given site, and only this one is a fit for the sort of question you seem to have in mind.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Examining the three SE sites which are linked in the question:

- [Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/) is software used by mathematicians, engineers, and scientists of all stripes.  Hence questions about the Mathematica software are appropriate over there, and not basic mathematical questions.
- [Math Educators](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/) is meant for questions about *teaching* mathematics.  These are typically questions asked by tutors, professors, instructors, graduate TAs, and/or primary/secondary school teachers.  Questions about pedagogy and teaching methodology are appropriate there, and not basic mathematical questions.
- [Math Overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/) is meant for professional mathematicians.  The questions that are asked there are about research level mathematics, and not basic mathematical questions.

All of this information can be obtained by skimming the [help center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help) pages on each one of those websites (the URLS are of the form `https://math.stackexchange.com/help`; replace `math` with the appropriate site identifier; or just click the question mark in the upper right).

In short, none of the sites linked above are appropriate for basic mathematical questions.  The only site on the SE network where such questions are appropriate is [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: As a footnote, there's also [History of Science and Mathematics](//hsm.stackexchange.com/), which does what it says in the name.

Answer (score 5):

Math.StackExchange is the best site on the StackExchange network for most people to seek answers to typical mathematical problems.

Comment: thank you so I have any  doubts in math and I would like know what is the best site for ask this kind of question